# How to GUI - Using paintcomponent() to initialize a GUI and then to add GUI based on mouse

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, paintcomponent

Title says it all... My friend and I are doing this and we have no idea why Ball.java isn't actually making the balls in the gamePanel and then making the GUI. This is 8-ball pool, by the way. Here is the code:

### Driver or Final2

```
import javax.swing.*; 
import java.awt.*; 
import java.io.*; 
import java.util.*; 
import java.awt.event.*; 
import java.awt.Color; 
import java.awt.Graphics; 
import java.awt.Graphics2D; 
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D; 
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;

public class Final2 implements ActionListener {
    JPanel titlePanel, gamePanel, buttonPanel;
    JLabel titleLabel, turnLabel, oneTypeLabel, twoTypeLabel;
    JButton newGameButton;
    int turn;
    String oneType,twoType;

    public JPanel createContentPane() {
        turn = 0;
        oneType = "";
        twoType = "";

        JPanel totalGUI = new JPanel();
        totalGUI.setLayout(null);

        titlePanel = new JPanel();
        titlePanel.setLayout(null);
        titlePanel.setLocation(10,0);
        titlePanel.setSize(500,100);
        totalGUI.add(titlePanel);
        titleLabel = new JLabel("8-ball Pool");
        titleLabel.setLocation(25,10);
        titleLabel.setSize(100,20);
        titleLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(0);
        titleLabel.setForeground(Color.red);
        titlePanel.add(titleLabel);
        gamePanel = new gamePanel();
        gamePanel.setLayout(null);
        gamePanel.setLocation(200,250);
        gamePanel.setSize(864,432); //this needs to be turned into 864x432 later
        gamePanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
        totalGUI.add(gamePanel);

        buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        buttonPanel.setLocation(900,40);
        buttonPanel.setSize(200,40);
        totalGUI.add(buttonPanel);
        turnLabel = new JLabel("" + turn);
        turnLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(0);
        titlePanel.add(turnLabel);        
        oneTypeLabel = new JLabel(oneType);
        oneTypeLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(0);
        oneTypeLabel.setForeground(Color.red);
        buttonPanel.add(oneTypeLabel);
        twoTypeLabel = new JLabel(twoType);
        twoTypeLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(0);
        twoTypeLabel.setForeground(Color.blue);
        buttonPanel.add(twoTypeLabel);
        newGameButton = new JButton("New Game");
        newGameButton.addActionListener(this);
        buttonPanel.add(newGameButton);

        return totalGUI;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource() == newGameButton) {
        }
    }

    public static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("8-ball Pool!");

        //Create and set up the content pane.
        Final gui = new Final();
        frame.setContentPane(gui.createContentPane());

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(1000, 1500);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                 createAndShowGUI();
                }
         });
    } }
```

### gamePanel

```
import javax.swing.*; 
import java.awt.*; 
import java.io.*; 
import java.util.*; 
import java.awt.event.*; 
import java.awt.Color; 
import java.awt.Graphics; 
import java.awt.Graphics2D; 
import  java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D; 
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;

public class gamePanel extends JPanel {
    private boolean setup = true;

    public gamePanel() {    setOpaque(true);    setBackground(Color.GREEN);  
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {    /*  Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;     Ellipse2D circle = new Ellipse2D.Double(100 - 18,100
-18,18,18);     g2.setColor(Color.BLUE);    g2.draw(circle);    Rectangle2D rect = new Rectangle2D.Double(100 - 18,100 -5,18,5);
    g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);   g2.draw(rect); */
    super.paintComponent(g);    //column 1  //1     /*
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);    g.drawOval(624,206,20,20);
    g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);   g.fillOval(625,207,18,18);

    //column 2  //14    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);        
    g.drawOval(644,196,20,20);  g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    g.fillOval(645,197,18,18);

    //4     g.setColor(Color.BLACK);    g.drawOval(644,216,20,20);
    g.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);  g.fillOval(645,217,18,18);
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);    g.fillRect(645 + 7,217,5,18);

    //column 3  //5     g.setColor(Color.BLACK);    g.drawOval(664,186,20,20);
    g.setColor(Color.ORANGE.darker());  g.fillOval(665,187,18,18);
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);    g.fillRect(665 + 7,187,5,18);

    //8     g.setColor(Color.BLACK);    g.drawOval(664,206,20,20);
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);    g.fillOval(665,207,18,18);

    //13    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);    g.drawOval(664,226,20,20);
    g.setColor(Color.ORANGE.darker());  g.fillOval(665,227,18,18);

    //column 4  //11    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawOval(684,176,20,20);  g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.fillOval(685,177,18,18);  g.setColor(Color.WHITE);    g.fillRect(685
+ 7,177,5,18);

    //2     g.setColor(Color.BLACK);            g.drawOval(684,196,20,20);
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);     g.fillOval(685,197,18,18);

    //12    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);            g.drawOval(684,216,20,20);
    g.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);  g.fillOval(685,217,18,18);

    //9 (looks suspiciously like solid yellow)  g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawOval(684,236,20,20);  g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    g.fillOval(685,237,18,18);  g.setColor(Color.WHITE);    g.fillRect(685
+ 7,237,5,18);

    //column 5  //7     g.setColor(Color.BLACK);        
    g.drawOval(704,166,20,20);
    g.setColor(Color.ORANGE.darker().darker().darker().darker());
    g.fillOval(705,167,18,18);

    //10    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);    g.drawOval(704,186,20,20);
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);     g.fillOval(705,187,18,18);
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);    g.fillRect(705 + 7,187,5,18);

    //15    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);    g.drawOval(704,206,20,20);
    g.setColor(Color.ORANGE.darker().darker().darker().darker());
    g.fillOval(705,207,18,18);  g.setColor(Color.WHITE);    g.fillRect(705
+ 7,207,5,18);

    //3     g.setColor(Color.BLACK);    g.drawOval(704,226,20,20);
    g.setColor(Color.RED);  g.fillOval(705,227,18,18);

    //6     g.setColor(Color.BLACK);    g.drawOval(704,246,20,20);
    g.setColor(Color.GREEN);    g.fillOval(705,247,18,18);
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);    g.fillRect(705 + 7,247,5,18);

    //the almighty cue ball     g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawOval(304,206,20,20);  g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.fillOval(305,207,18,18);  */  if (setup) {
        setup = false;
        //column 1
        //1
        Ball ball1 = new Ball(1,624,206);
        this.add(ball1);
        this.update(this.getGraphics()); //this breaks everything yay

        //column 2
        //6
        Ball ball6 = new Ball(6,644,196);
        //12
        Ball ball12 = new Ball(12,644,216);

        //column 3
        //13
        Ball ball13 = new Ball(13,664,186);
        //8
        Ball ball8 = new Ball(8,664,206);
        //5
        Ball ball5 = new Ball(5,664,226);

        //column 4
        //11
        Ball ball11 = new Ball(11,684,176);
        //2
        Ball ball2 = new Ball(2,684,196);
        //4
        Ball ball4 = new Ball(4,684,216);   }
    } }
```

### Ball

```
import javax.swing.*; 
import java.awt.*; 
import java.io.*; 
import java.util.*; 
import java.awt.event.*; 
import java.awt.Color;

public class Ball extends gamePanel {
    private int xcor,ycor;
    private int rxcor,rycor,radius;
    private int num;

    public Ball(int n,int x,int y) {
        num = n;
        xcor = x;
        ycor = y;
        radius = 9;
        this.setVisible(true);

    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        boolean isStriped = (num 8);
        int color = num%8;

        if (color == 0) {
         if (isStriped) {
                //8ball
                g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                g.drawOval(xcor,ycor,20,20);
                g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                g.fillOval(xcor+1,ycor+1,18,18);
         }
         else {
                //cue ball is 16
                g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                g.drawOval(xcor,ycor,20,20);
                g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                g.fillOval(xcor+1,ycor+1,18,18);
         }        
        }        
        else {
         if (color == 1) {
                if (isStriped) {
                 //9ball
                 g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                 g.drawOval(xcor,ycor,20,20);
                 g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                 g.fillOval(xcor+1,ycor+1,18,18);
                 g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
                 g.fillOval(xcor+8,ycor+1,5,18);
                }
                else {
                 //1ball
                 g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                 g.drawOval(xcor,ycor,20,20);
                 g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
                 g.fillOval(xcor+1,ycor+1,18,18);
                }
         }
         else {
                if (color == 2) {
                 if (isStriped) {
                        //10ball
                        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                        g.drawOval(xcor,ycor,20,20);
                        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                        g.fillOval(xcor+1,ycor+1,18,18);
                        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                        g.fillOval(xcor+8,ycor+1,5,18);
                 }
                 else {
                        //2ball
                        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                        g.drawOval(xcor,ycor,20,20);
                        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                        g.fillOval(xcor+1,ycor+1,18,18);
                 }
                }
                else {
                 if (color == 3) {
                        if (isStriped) {
                         //11ball
                         g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                         g.drawOval(xcor,ycor,20,20);
                         g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                         g.fillOval(xcor+1,ycor+1,18,18);
                         g.setColor(Color.RED);
                         g.fillOval(xcor+8,ycor+1,5,18);
                        }
                        else {
                         //3ball
                         g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                         g.drawOval(xcor,ycor,20,20);
                         g.setColor(Color.RED);
                         g.fillOval(xcor+1,ycor+1,18,18);
                        }
                 }
                 else{
                        if (color == 4) {
                         if (isStriped) {
                                //12ball
                                g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                                g.drawOval(xcor,ycor,20,20);
                                g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                                g.fillOval(xcor+1,ycor+1,18,18);
                                g.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
                                g.fillRect(xcor+8,ycor+1,5,18);
                         }
                         else {
                                //4ball
                                g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                                g.drawOval(xcor,ycor,20,20);
                                g.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
                                g.fillRect(xcor+1,ycor+1,18,18);
                         }
                        }
                        else {
                         if (color == 5) {
                                if (isStriped) {
                                 //13ball
                                 g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                                 g.drawOval(xcor,ycor,20,20);
                                 g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                                 g.fillOval(xcor+1,ycor+1,18,18);
                                 g.setColor(Color.ORANGE.darker());
                                 g.fillRect(xcor+8,ycor+1,5,18);
                                }
                                else {
                                 //5ball
                                 g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                                 g.drawOval(xcor,ycor,20,20);
                                 g.setColor(Color.ORANGE.darker());
                                 g.fillOval(xcor+1,ycor+1,18,18);
                                }
                         }
                         else {
                                if (color == 6) {
                                 if (isStriped) {
                                        //14ball
                                        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                                        g.drawOval(xcor,ycor,20,20);
                                        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                                        g.fillOval(xcor+1,ycor+1,18,18);
                                        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                                        g.fillOval(xcor+8,ycor+1,5,18);
                                 }
                                 else {
                                        //6ball
                                        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                                        g.drawOval(xcor,ycor,20,20);
                                        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                                        g.fillOval(xcor+1,ycor+1,18,18);
                                 }
                                }
                                else {
                                 if (color == 7) {
                                        if (isStriped) {
                                         //15ball
                                         g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                                         g.drawOval(xcor,ycor,20,20);
                                         g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                                         g.fillOval(xcor+1,ycor+1,18,18);
                                         g.setColor(Color.ORANGE.darker().darker().darker().darker());
                                         g.fillOval(xcor+8,ycor+1,5,18);
                                        }
                                        else {
                                         //7ball
                                         g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                                         g.drawOval(xcor,ycor,20,20);
                                         g.setColor(Color.ORANGE.darker().darker().darker().darker());
                                         g.fillOval(xcor+1,ycor+1,18,18);
                                        }
                                 }
                                }
                         }
                        }
                 }
                }
         }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Heck lot of code! Do you really want we debug that code for you?

Comment: Please, at the very least, make sure your code in the question is readable easily... it is not well formatted.

Comment: Don't mix code formatting an quoted text.  Use code formatting for code, input/output & structured documents like HTML or XML.  To do that, select the sample and click the `{}` button above the messaged posting/editing form.

Comment: See how much better it looks now?  It was a mess.  I hope I've convinced you, since I don't do that for people often.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the thing. You don't want a bunch of `JPanel`s as balls. You should just have *one* `JPanel` to paint on and use *only* that one `paintComponent` method for all the Balls. So you `Ball` class doesn't need to extend *anything* at all. The `Ball` class should only be a model to hold data, such ass the RGB color. You should also a draw method in the ball class that take a `Graphics` object as an argument, and draws the ball

```
public class Ball {
    int R, G, B;
    boolean striped;
    int x, y;

    public Ball(int R, int G, int B, boolean striped) {
        this.R = R:
        this.G = G;
        this.B = B;
        this.striped = striped;
    }

    public void drawBall(Graphics g) {
        if (isStriped) {
            // draw the ball with the values from this class
        }
        else {
            // draw the ball with the values from this class
        } 
    }
}
```

Then in the class that you're doing the actual drawing with, you want to have a list of `Ball` objects

```
public class TablePanel extends JPanel {
    List<Ball> balls = new ArrayList<Ball>();

    public TablePanel(){
        makeBalls();
    }

    public void makeBalls(){
        balls.add(new Ball(213, 2, 255, true);
        // add more balls
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        for (Ball ball : balls) {
            ball.drawBall(g);
        }
    }
}
```

You can see all I did was use the method `ball.drawBall(g);`. The ball will appear. But you will also need to specify the `x` and `y` location of the ball too. Then when you need to animate the balls, just change their `x` and `y` fields.

Here's an example

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class SorryPoolTable extends JPanel{

    List<ABall> balls = new ArrayList<ABall>();

    public SorryPoolTable(){
        makeBalls();
    }

    public void makeBalls(){
        balls.add(new ABall(213, 2, 255, true, 125, 25));
        balls.add(new ABall(65, 34, 25, true, 150, 135));
        balls.add(new ABall(124, 211, 45, true, 160, 180));
        balls.add(new ABall(35, 123, 255, true, 200, 200));
        balls.add(new ABall(45, 222, 255, true, 50, 200));
        balls.add(new ABall(65, 92, 155, true, 125, 175));

    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        for (ABall ball : balls) {
            ball.drawBall(g);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(200, 300);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Sorry Pool Table");
                frame.add(new SorryPoolTable());
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}

class ABall {
    int R, G, B;
    boolean striped;
    int x, y;

    public ABall(int R, int G, int B, boolean striped, int x, int y) {
        this.R = R;
        this.G = G;
        this.B = B;
        this.striped = striped;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void drawBall(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(new Color(R, G, B));
        g.fillOval(x, y, 20, 20);
    }
}
```

[image]

---

**UPDATE**

Example of `MouseMotionListener`. This is a very simple example. The stick doesn't rotate or anthing. Take a look at [**Graphics2D tutorial**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/) for more complex details about how you can accomplish this

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


public class PoolStick extends JPanel{
    int x = 100;
    int y = 100;

    public PoolStick() {
        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                Point p = e.getPoint();
                x = (int)p.getX();
                y = (int)p.getY();
                repaint();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.fillRect(x, y, 5, 200);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(200, 300);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Sorry Pool Table");
                frame.add(new PoolStick());
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks! ALso, how do I make a rectangle that follows the mouse around, something along the lines of a custom cursor that represents the stick in pool. I understand how to initialize GUI, but how do I make it so everytime I move my mouse a rectangle follows my mouse?

Comment: You need a `MouseMotionListener` and @Override the `mouseMoved` method. get the cursor location with `e.getPoint();` and `reapaint() with new `x` `y` cordinates

Answer (score 1):

I think you have two problems here:

1. You don't override
   [paintComponent()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintComponent%28java.awt.Graphics%29)
   properly. This is a `protected` method, not `public`. If you add
   `@Override` annotation on this method then the compiler will
   complain. This is a really good reason for adding this annotation
   every time you need to override some method.
2. `Ball` class extends from `gamePanel` so when you call `super.paintComponent(g)` in the first class it will call `paintComponent(g)` on its ancestor. If you add balls inside `gamePanel` then you'll get an endless loop that will probably cause a stack overflow.

#### Off-topic

Always follow [Java Code Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf).

Comment: The compiler will _not_ complain about `public` or `protected` with `paintComponent`. You can override with a higher visibility but not a lower one. `public` is higher than `protected` so there's no problem

Comment: @peeskillet Noted! But in this case is not good at all make `paintComponent()` public, is it?